# Hide item for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models:

```
model User id:integer name:string

model Item id:integer name:string
```

What is best way to do function:

All user can view all items. Current user can "hide the item". Then the item it is not shown, but shown to users who do not have hidden item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a secondary model to handle the 'hide' logic for individual items.  The following code illustrates how you might do this using a subquery:

```
class HiddenItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item      
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hidden_items

  def self.visible_for_user(user)
    subquery = user.hidden_items.select("hidden_items.item_id").to_sql
    where("items.id NOT IN (#{subquery})")
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hidden_items

  def visible_items
    Item.visible_for_user(self)
  end      
end
```

Now you can get the non-hidden items for a user:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.visible_items
```

If you wanted to hide an item, you can do this:

```
user.hidden_items.create(item_id: item.id)
```